# Old Join Syntax multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to join four tables together using the old inner join syntax in sql server 2008 and can't figure it out, I keep getting a cartesian product. I've tried multiple different ways but still get repeating results.
where's my error?

code:

```
SELECT 
     TC.intCustomerID
    ,TC.strFirstName + ',' + TC.strLastName AS strCustomer
    ,TCO.intOrderIndex
    ,TCO.dtmOrder
    ,TI.intItemID
    ,TI.strItem
    ,TCOI.intQuantity
FROM
     TCustomers AS TC
    ,TCustomerOrders AS TCO
    ,TCustomerOrderItems AS TCOI
    ,TItems AS TI
WHERE 
    TC.intCustomerID = TCOI.intCustomerID
AND TCO.intOrderIndex = TCOI.intOrderIndex
AND TCOI.intItemID = TI.intItemID
ORDER BY 
     TC.intCustomerID
    ,strCustomer
```

Comment: could we get your schema for those 4 tables ?

Comment: And maybe some sample data

Answer (score 0):

i don't know your tables but it looks strange to read `WHERE 
    TC.intCustomerID = TCOI.intCustomerID` for the first table, i guess it should be `WHERE 
    TC.intCustomerID = TCO.intCustomerID` ?

If TCustomers (TC) contains all your customers and TCustomerOrders (TCO) your orders, i guess the order is linked to a customer?

Your query looks to link directly the customer to the order's items, which might be wrong if the order has more than one item.

By the way, why is the customer ID stored in the TCustomerOrderItems table?

I might be totally wrong, you should give some sample datas as others said though